# Image in GridViewItem on previous Page blocking file access

Tags: windows-runtime, storagefile

I have a Page **Ingredients.xaml** with a GridView. This GridView displays a list of `Ingredient` objects. For each item, an image is displayed by binding to a string property of the `Ingredient` object containing the file's path (in the app's local folder).

When I click on an item, the app navigates to **Ingredient.xaml**, a details page, where the image as well as all the details are displayed. There is functionality to set a new image or replace/remove the current one.

When there is no image yet, everything works like a charm. However, as soon as a file exists already, I get the following error when trying to either delete or replace the current file: 
"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".

At first I thought the Image in **Ingredient.xaml** was the issue, since it was still showing the image I was trying to delete. So i added the following line to the code:

```cs
this.ingredientImage.Source = null;
```

The code was still throwing the exception, though. So I tried something else: I removed the Image from the GridView in **Ingredients.xaml**. The only place the image is shown not is in **Ingredient.xaml**. When I try to replace/delete the image, `Image.Source` is set to null and the file is successfully replaced/deleted.

Apparently the Image in the GridView on the previous Page is still blocking the file, but I have no idea how I could release the file when I navigate away.

Comment: How do you display the images in Ingredients.xaml? Depending on how they are loaded - there might be different ways to close the image files.

Comment: I was setting the Source property to the URI string, that was causing the error above. I have now changed the way I use the images: I load them when I need them and copy them to a BitmapImage instead of just a string. That's working perfectly now.

Comment: Glad you solved that!

Comment: @DavideDeSantis I'm having this exact same problem. Can you comment on how you "load them when I need them, and copy them to a BitmapImage"? I'm binding to a URI because its serializable...

Comment: @7200rpm Instead of storing the image's path in a string property, I now store the image itself in a `WriteableBitmap` property. Whenever I load the ingredients, the controller creates a new `WriteableBitmap` using the current real image as template. Then, in WPF, I just bind the `Image`'s `Source` Property to my `WriteableBitmap` property. This way I can delete/alter the source image without encountering the access denied error.